# Promises: Give status update without returning from fn

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function that calls three asynchronous functions.
I'd like to notify the callee everytime one of these functions is done, to show the user the progress of the actions.

Is there a way to kind of "notify" the callee without returning from the fn?

```
function updateDataset(...) {
    return a().then(function () {
        console.log("[someService] Task 1 done...");

        return b(...).then(function (entries) {
            console.log("[someService] Task 2 done...");

            var requests = c(entries);

            return Promise.all(requests).then(function () {
                console.log("[someService] Task 3 done...");

                return true;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The callee looks like this:

```
someService.updateDataset(...).then(function (isSucc) {
    //Do stuff
});
```

It would be awesome if I could just chain `.notified()` to the promise chain...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32909694/2446102

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could pass a callback and handle the notification there, additionally you can "flatten" the chain so every promise returns and you don't have a `.then` inside another `.then`

i refactored a little bit your code just to show you a possible approach.

```
function updateDataset(notificationCb) {
    return a()
    .then(function () {
        console.log("[someService] Task 1 done...");
        notificationCb(1); //first ended
        return b(...);
    })
    .then(function (entries) {
        console.log("[someService] Task 2 done...");
        var requests = c(entries) ;
        notificationCb(2); //second ended
        return Promise.all(requests);
     })
    .then(function () {
       console.log("[someService] Task 3 done...");
       //here there's no need to call the callback because the fn returns to the caller
       return true;
    });
}
```

and the caller:

```
someService.updateDataset(function(notification){
 //here you choose the strategy to handle the notification
 if(notification === 1){ 
   //first has ended.. etc.
 } else{

 }
})
.then(function (isSucc) {
    //Do stuff
});
```