# Resolved promise waits for inner promise to be resolved

Tags: javascript, promise

I'd like to have a promise to a promise, something like this:

```
let first = new Promise(resolveFirst => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolveFirst("resolved!");
    }, 2000)
});

let second = new Promise(resolveSecond => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolveSecond(first);
    }, 10)
});

second.then(secondValue => {
    console.log("second value: ", secondValue);
    secondValue.then(firstValue => {
        console.log("first value: ", firstValue);
    });
});
```

So that the `console.log("second value: ", secondValue);` is printed after `10` millies and then the `console.log("first value: ", firstValue)` will be printed `2000` afterwards.

What happens though is that I get:

> second value:  resolved!

And an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: secondValue.then is not a function

Together after `2010` millies.

It seems that when the second promise is resolved, and the first one is returned then it automatically waits for this first promise to resolve as well.

Why is that? And how do I break between them?

---

#### Edit

Here's a solution that was posted on facebook using `Array.reduce()`:

```
const runPromisesInSeries = 
    ps => ps.reduce((p, next) => 
        p.then(next), Promise.resolve());

const delay = d => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, d));
runPromisesInSeries([() => delay(1000), () => delay(2000)]);
//executes each promise sequentially, taking a total of 3 seconds to complete
```

(https://www.facebook.com/addyosmaniofficial/photos/a.10151435123819601.1073741825.129712729600/10155386805609601/?type=3&theater)

Comment: Do you really need to return the `first` promise like this? Problem is that when you call `second.then()`, you will resolve all of the promise chain (you are creating that chain by resolving `first` from `second`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, a promise  that is resolved with a second promise takes on the value and state of the 2nd promise after the 2nd promise becomes settled (fulfilled or rejected), waiting for it to be settled as necessary.

It is not possible to fulfill a promise with a promise or thenable object (any object with a `then` method`) value unless the promise library is seriously flawed (older versions of JQuery would fulfill their own promise objects with a promise object from a different library).

Promise rejection does not have the same checks in place and will happily pass a promise object down the chain without waiting for it to be resolved. So you could reject the 2nd promise with the first and pick it up in a `catch` clause.

Although technically feasible I strongly advise against doing so except to prove it can be done - it's a maintenance issue for a third party trying to understand the code.

While you could pass the promise as an object property down the success channel of a promise chain, re-analysis of promise composition may provide a better or more standard solution. E.G. `Promise.all` waits for for two or more independent promises to be fulfilled before proceeding on a common task.

Comment: I'll need to change a few things, but `Promise.all` will probably work for me.

Answer (score 1):

That's just part of their charm: If your promise A resolves to a thenable B, then A resolves only after B resolves, and A takes B's resolved value. That's part of both [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-41) and [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-resolve-functions), as part of the "promise resolution procedure".

You can see some of the advantages of that if (say) one action requires an action before its completion (like login), or requires loading another page of results, or has retry logic of its own.

Though it's not very idiomatic, if you want to return an unresolved promise immediately without waiting for it, you can do so by passing it in an `{object}` or `[array]`, but there might not be much reason for that: Other than waiting for its completion, what would you do with a returned promise?

Comment: What if the completion of the 2nd promise takes a while and I want to inform the user that the 1st promise has completed and we're now waiting for the 2nd one?

Comment: @NitzanTomer That would be the kind of granularity you could get if you return an `{object}`, but if you think of a Promise as a pure abstraction for "a correct value whenever it arrives regardless of the intermediate delays/steps", then you may not want to reuse the return value as the channel to say "still thinking about it, here's the Promise to the next value". Similar to [other requests for promise "progress"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32909694/1426891), you may want to consider an Observable, a field you set, or a callback function you call.

Comment: I'll probably end up separating between the two promises and then use `Promise.all` as @Traktor53 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain `then` only to a promise.
`secondValue` is not a promise, it's just the value that returned when you called the `second` promise. or the `resolved` value from that promise.

If you want that to work, try this:

```
let first = new Promise(resolveFirst => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolveFirst("resolved!");
  }, 2000)
});

let second = new Promise(resolveSecond => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolveSecond(first);
  }, 10)
});

second.then(secondValue => {
    console.log("second value: ", secondValue);
    /** first is a Promise. return a promise, and the next "then"
     * will pass the result of that Promise.
     */
    return first
  })
  .then(firstValue => {
    console.log(firstValue)
  })
```

## EDIT 1

Further explanation for why `second` promise resolved the eventual value (`string`) of the `first` promise, and not the promise itself, [can be found on mdn:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

**Promise.resolve()**

> if the value was a promise, that object becomes the result of the call to Promise.resolve; otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value.

Comment: `secondValue` is indeed a promise, as I resolve `second` like so: `resolveSecond(first)` where `first` is a promise.

Comment: `secondValue` is a `string`. try to write `console.log(typeof secondValue)` and the result will be `string`

Comment: Ok, it is a string, but I'd expect it to be the promise, that's the entire problem and the reason I'm asking the question.

Comment: see my addition to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not using `Promise.resolve` but the reason is the same. I will probably use `Promise.all` as was suggested by @Traktor53.