# Detect if function was called with "then"

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm making my own ajax function like jQuery and this is what I have so far

```
const ajax = function(options){
    const defaults = {
        type: 'GET',
        url: window.location,
        data: {},
        success: function(){},
        error: function(){}
    },
    opts = {...defaults, ...options};

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){
        opts.success.call(this, xhr.response, xhr);
    });
    xhr.addEventListener("error", function(){
        opts.error.call(this, xhr);
    });
    xhr.open(opts.type, opts.url);
    xhr.send();
}
```

and I can call it like

```
ajax({
    success: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

It works. But I want to add *optional* promise to it. So I want to be able to call this function exactly like this but also like

```
ajax().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I'm new to promises so I'm not sure how to modify the function such that I can detect whether to resolve/reject or call callbacks. Also am I doing something that is considered bad practice?

```
const ajax = function(options){
    const defaults = {
        type: 'GET',
        url: window.location,
        data: {},
        success: function(){},
        error: function(){}
    },
    opts = {...defaults, ...options};

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){
            resolve(xhr.response);
        });
        xhr.addEventListener("error", function(){
            reject(xhr);
        });
        xhr.open(opts.type, opts.url);
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Comment: "*I want to add optional promise to it.*" - don't. Nobody should design new callback APIs in 2022. Just always return a promise. Do not accept `error` and `success` options. Make people write good, modern code, do not let them use legacy patterns.

Comment: What about the xhr's progress event? Can that be handled with promises?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32909893/476.

Comment: That looks like a callback. And that's what I have read in other places too - promises are not a good candidate for progress tracking. So I'll have to use callbacks for some things and promises for others. Might as well keep all the callbacks and allow promise functionality.

Comment: @Whip There were no `progress` handlers in your code so I didn't discuss that. Yes, for events that occur any number of times, accepting callbacks is still fine; the other approach would be to return a stream (next to the promise) that the caller can attach their callback to, but there's no built-in solution for that yet. But no, this is not an excuse to "keep all the callbacks".